# How to split excel columns into multiple rows

Tags: excel, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula, powerquery, google-sheets-query

I get exports from an event registration form, where each order(row) contains order date, purchase price, and info for between 1-4 registrants. Each registrant has columns for first name, last name, and date of birth. What I need is to split up these rows such that each individual person is on their own row, with first, last, and DOB on the row, ideally along with the other order information duplicated too.

This may be confusing so I have mockup date for the form I get exports in, and the form I'd like to convert them to.

What I get:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xt64Re2CTlbQnHuRy1dQaFeNV5OmETfW/view?usp=sharing

What I want:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/156WmiQ4Tx4JGB5FYLTqHBuVmJqi20pRZ/view?usp=sharing

[I found this tutorial](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/a-super-easy-way-to-generate-new-records-from-multi-value-columns-using-excels-power-query/) which seem very close to what I want using Excel Power Query, but it is describing a method for when the multiple items are in one column separated by comma. My situation is a bit different and I can't make it work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Pick either Excel or Google Sheets please, and then remove the tags from the one you're not using, thanks.

Comment: @bigben - My question is about the data, I don't have a preference on how it's solved. Both GSheets and Excel seem to have different methods to solve it, I just couldn't get either to work and I'd be OK with either. That being said, if I broke a community rule by tagging both apps, I'd be happy to remove one (it's my impression that Excel may be the better capability to do this, but I'd prefer a GSuite solution, so I don't have a starghtforward choice here). What do you recommend?

Answer (score 0):

Below PowerQuery works on sample data set you had, when loaded into range **Table1**

Written dynamically for any number of First/Last/DOB sets of columns; You had 4 this would handle any number of them

Paste into Home ... Advanced Editor...

a bit long winded to separate the steps and make it visible

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Order Date", type date}}),

// Get names of all First, Last and DOB fields
ColumnsToCombine1 = List.Select(Table.ColumnNames(#"Changed Type"), each Text.Contains(_, "(First)")),
ColumnsToCombine2 = List.Select(Table.ColumnNames(#"Changed Type"), each Text.Contains(_, "(Last)")),
ColumnsToCombine3 = List.Select(Table.ColumnNames(#"Changed Type"), each Text.Contains(_, "DOB")),

//Convert to Text, so we can merge columns; for date fields, convert to date first
#"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Changed Type", (List.Transform(ColumnsToCombine3 ,each {_,type date}))),
#"Changed Type2" = Table.TransformColumnTypes (#"Changed Type1",List.Transform(Table.ColumnNames(#"Changed Type1"), each {_, type text})),

// convert all First, Last and DOB fields into three comma separated columns
#"Combined1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type2" , "First", each Text.Combine(Record.FieldValues(Record.SelectFields(_,ColumnsToCombine1)),", ")),
#"Combined2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Combined1", "Last", each Text.Combine(Record.FieldValues(Record.SelectFields(_,ColumnsToCombine2)),", ")),
#"Combined3" = Table.AddColumn(#"Combined2", "DOB", each Text.Combine(Record.FieldValues(Record.SelectFields(_,ColumnsToCombine3)),", ")),

#"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(Combined3,{"ID", "Order Date", "Quantity", "Payment", "First", "Donate", "Last", "DOB"}),

//expand all comma separated columns into their own rows
TableTransform = Table.Combine(List.Transform(List.Transform(Table.ToRecords(#"Removed Other Columns" ), (x) => List.Transform(Record.ToList(x), each Text.Split(_,","))), each Table.FromColumns(_, Table.ColumnNames(#"Removed Other Columns" )))),

#"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(TableTransform,{"ID", "Order Date", "Quantity", "First", "Last", "DOB", "Payment", "Donate"}),
#"Filled Down" = Table.FillDown(#"Reordered Columns",{"ID", "Order Date", "Quantity", "Payment", "Donate"}),
#"Changed Type3" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Filled Down",{{"DOB", type date}, {"Order Date", type date}, {"Payment", type number}, {"Donate", type number}, {"Quantity", type number}, {"First", type text}, {"Last", type text}})
in #"Changed Type3"
```

Alternate version, hard coded to 4 tables, based on Ron's

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
colNames = Table.ColumnNames(Source),
Table1 = Table.Skip(Table.DemoteHeaders(Table.SelectColumns(Source,List.RemoveMatchingItems(colNames , List.Select(colNames, each Text.Contains(_, "-2") or Text.Contains(_, "-3") or Text.Contains(_, "-4"))))),1),
Table2 = Table.Skip(Table.DemoteHeaders(Table.SelectColumns(Source,List.RemoveMatchingItems(colNames , List.Select(colNames, each Text.Contains(_, "-1") or Text.Contains(_, "-3") or Text.Contains(_, "-4"))))),1),
Table3 = Table.Skip(Table.DemoteHeaders(Table.SelectColumns(Source,List.RemoveMatchingItems(colNames , List.Select(colNames, each Text.Contains(_, "-1") or Text.Contains(_, "-2") or Text.Contains(_, "-4"))))),1),
Table4 = Table.Skip(Table.DemoteHeaders(Table.SelectColumns(Source,List.RemoveMatchingItems(colNames , List.Select(colNames, each Text.Contains(_, "-1") or Text.Contains(_, "-2") or Text.Contains(_, "-3"))))),1),
combined = Table1  & Table2 & Table3 & Table4,
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(combined, each ([Column4] <> null)),
#"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Filtered Rows",{{"Column1", Order.Ascending}}),
#"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Sorted Rows",{{"Column2", "Order Date"}, {"Column3", "Quantity"}, {"Column4", "First"}, {"Column5", "Last"}, {"Column6", "DOB"}, {"Column7", "Payment"}, {"Column8", "Donate"}, {"Column1", "ID"}}),
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Renamed Columns",{{"ID", type number}, {"Quantity", type number}, {"Payment", type number}, {"Donate", type number}, {"Order Date", type date}, {"DOB", type date}, {"First", type text}, {"Last", type text}})
in #"Changed Type"
```

Comment: I did it differently and wonder how to gauge efficiency of different methods. Any suggestions?

Comment: Love to see. Can you add?

Comment: Posted.  Although still a work in progress.  I'd be interested in your thoughts.

Comment: interesting. I wrote a second version which is similar to most of the steps you did, posted

Comment: I had started working on this for a different problem (with repeated pairs of columns), but, with help, eventually figured out how to generalize to `N` groups of columns. I just don't know whether multiple tables; or your first posted method; would be "better"

Comment: yea, I'm not currently motivated to time, maybe original poster will tell us

Answer (score 0):

Here is another PQ method to accomplish this.

I post it as a PQ beginner, and I have no idea whether this method or the first method posted is more efficient and/or scalable

It is still a work in progress, as I have fixed column names in some of the steps, and I want to make that more generalized eventually.  But this problem of repeating groups of columns comes up from time to time.

**Source Data**

[image]

This method:

- Reorder the columns to put the "common columns" together, which, in this case, would be the first three and the last two.
- Demote the header row and transpose the table
- Process the first column so as to create a proper list of what will be eventual column headers.

  - Split this table into multiple tables where

    - the first table represents the common columns
    - the other tables represent each repeating group of columns
- Combine the first table with each of the other tables
- Combine the resulting tables
- Transpose back to the original column/row orientation, and promote the first row to headers.
- Clean up by removing nulls and sorting
- Reorder the columns to put the first three and last two back where they were initially.

*Note:  You'll need to change `Table1` in the code to the actual table name, if it is different*

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],

        colNames = Table.ColumnNames(Source),

            commonTableColumnCount = 5,

           colOrder = List.Combine({List.FirstN(colNames,3),List.LastN(colNames,2),List.Range(colNames,3,List.Count(colNames)-commonTableColumnCount)}),

    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(Source,colOrder),
    
    //Demote Headers and transpose
    transpose1 = Table.Transpose(Table.DemoteHeaders(#"Reordered Columns")),

    //Split up Column 1 to create multiple matched names
    split = Table.SplitColumn(transpose1, "Column1", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("-", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"Column1", "Column1.1"}),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(split, "Column1.1", Splitter.SplitTextByEachDelimiter({" "}, QuoteStyle.Csv, true), {"Column1.1.1", "Column1.1.2"}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{"Column1.1.1"}),
    #"Merged Columns" = Table.CombineColumns(#"Removed Columns",{"Column1", "Column1.1.2"},Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter(" ", QuoteStyle.None),"Column1"),

        commonTable = Table.Split(#"Merged Columns",commonTableColumnCount){0},
        record = Table.ToRecords(commonTable),
        
        //repeated tables
            //rem CommonTables Rows and split
            data = Table.Split(Table.RemoveRows(#"Merged Columns",0,commonTableColumnCount),3),

            //insert common rows into each table
            data1 = Table.InsertRows(data{0},0,record),

            //get final order of column names    
                colNames2 = Table.Column(data1,"Column1"),
                finalOrder = List.Combine({List.FirstN(colNames2,3),List.LastN(colNames2,List.Count(colNames2)-commonTableColumnCount), List.Range(colNames2,3,2)}),

            custom1 = List.Transform(data, each Table.InsertRows(_,0,record)),

            //Transpose and combine each Table
            custom2 = List.Transform(custom1, each(Table.PromoteHeaders(Table.Transpose(_),[PromoteAllScalars=true]))),
            
    #"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(custom2, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
    
        #"Expanded Column1" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Converted to Table","Column1",colNames2),

        //need to do this manually
        #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded Column1",{{"ID ", Int64.Type}, {"Order Date ", type date}, {"Quantity ", Int64.Type}, {"Payment ", Currency.Type}, {"Donate ", Currency.Type}, {"Name (First)", type text}, {"Name (Last)", type text}, {"DOB ", type date}}),

    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", each ([#"Name (Last)"] <> null)),

    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Filtered Rows",{"ID ", Order.Ascending}),

    #"Reordered Columns1" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Sorted Rows", finalOrder)
in
    #"Reordered Columns1"
```

**Reordered Table**

[image]